# Array changed by unrelated function

Tags: c, arrays

I'm experiencing some strange C behavior. I have an array (that I have labelled SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE) that is changing after a function call that is seemingly unrelated. My array is not global and the function call does not include the particular array. If anyone could figure out what is happening I would greatly appreciate it. Here is the main:

```
int main(){




    int generate4[16] = {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int propagate4[16] = {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    int SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE[4] = {0, 1, 0, 0};

    int carry_in16[4] = {1,2,1,1};
    int carry_in4[16] = {0};



    printf("\nShould be 1: %d", SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE[0]);
    printf("\nShould be 0: %d", SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE[1]);

    printf("\nSHOULD NOT CHANGE : ");
    print_binary_array(SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE, 4);



    // Here is where the problem is
    carry(propagate4, generate4, carry_in4, carry_in16, 64, 4);



    printf("\n\nShould be 0: %d", SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE[0]);
    printf("\nShould be 1: %d", SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE[1]);

    printf("\nSHOULD NOT CHANGE : ");
    print_binary_array(SHOULD_NOT_CHANGE, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the culprit function:

```
void carry(int* p, int* g, int* carry_in, int* group_carry, int size, int block)
{

for (int j = 0; j < block; j++){
    carry_in[j] = g[j]  +  p[j] * group_carry[j];

    for (int i = 1; i < block*4; i++){
        carry_in[4*j+i] = g[4*j+i]  +  p[4*j+i] * group_carry[j];
    }
}
}
```

And here is my output:

```
Should be 0: 0
Should be 1: 1
SHOULD NOT CHANGE : 0010

Should be 0: -13136
Should be 1: 0
SHOULD NOT CHANGE : 1-21471898220-13136
```

Comment: `carry_in[4*j+i]` - this will evaluate to `carry_in[4*3+15]` at the max, which means you will read off the end of the array, causing undefined behaviour(a segfault is not guaranteed).

Comment: @KarlReid Please post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing past the bounds of `carry_in` in function `carry`. `block` is 4, so `4*block` is 16. So `j` runs from 0 to 3, and `i` runs from 1 to 15. So `4*j+i` can be as large as 12+15 = 27, which is *way* larger than the maximum safe value of 15.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the for loop and it fixed my problem.